# tooltips in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, comments, tooltip, visual-assist

Sometimes I prefer to add a comment after declare a variable. For example:

```
bool isOverhwndChild1; // This is just an example to make my question clear and you can understand.
bool isOverhwndChild2; // This is just an example to make my question clear and you can understand.
bool isOverhwndChild3; // This is just an example to make my question clear and you can understand.
bool isOverhwndChild4; // This is just an example to make my question clear and you can understand.
```

I installed `Visual Assist X`.

If I move mouse over thses variables, a tooltip will show up and display the comments. But if the comment is very long, the width of the tooltip is very large.

I don't want to write as following since it distract me from the declaration of variables:

```
// This is just an example
// to make my question clear
// and you can understand.
bool isOverhwndChild1;

// This is just an example
// to make my question clear
// and you can understand.
bool isOverhwndChild2;

// This is just an example
// to make my question clear
// and you can understand.
bool isOverhwndChild3;

// This is just an example
// to make my question clear
// and you can understand.
bool isOverhwndChild4;
```

Is there a way to put a newline character in the comments in VS2010 so the tooltip will display multilines?

Comment: I don't seem to have this feature.  You're saying when you hover over a variable name, it shows you comments from the line it was declared on?

Comment: Ah, sorry about this. I installed VAssistX, and tooltip for comments is one of its feature, not of VS2010.

Comment: Ah gotcha - Interesting feature!

Comment: @Mike, I like this feature. It makes understanding the meaning of variables eaiser.

Comment: Many companies have coding rule restricting maximum length of a line with source code to 80 or 90 characters. Consider thinking about it.

Comment: @Mikhail: I am not a professional programmer and very unlikely to be one. But I know that it is a bad idea to write codes with very long lines.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment comments and tooltips are both long or they are both multilined. It would be nice if there were some mark-up (\n, < br />, or something like this) to have a better control here. Or an option where you can specify the maximum width of such a tooltip would solve your problem, too.

As a "workaround" I suggest to try to make the comments shorter even if the variable names get longer. If a variable is self-explanatory this even supports the readability of your code